# Angular material - mat-icon-button is not base aligned with adjacent element

Tags: html, css, angular, flexbox, angular-material

Hi all web developers,

I ran into an interesting issue on which I am scratching my head for the last two days.

We have created a private library of UI component in which we have styled angular material component based on our UX guidelines.

I am trying to base align mat-icon-button with adjacent  elements but it is moving a little bit up.
Because of having custom UX and custom density configuration, I have modified the code of how icon inside the mat-icon-button is getting centered aligned horizontally and vertically.
I have used flex box to do the same.

```css
    display: inline-flex !important;
    justify-content: center !important;
    align-items: center !important;
```

If I remove `align-items` css property then button is getting base aligned with adjacent element but the icon is not vertically centered.
I am trying to figure out what could be the reason behind this behavior and what could be the solution to fix this?

Stackblitz - https://stackblitz.com/edit/tzatnc-sr7fjj?file=src%2Fstyles.scss

With `align-items:center`
[image: With align-items:center]

Without `align-items:center`
[image: Without align-items:center]

Update - Adding `vertical-align:middle;` on icon button fixes this issue. But I want to understand why this is occurring in the first place